# parentNode() returns null while deleting multiple children nodes

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I can't find solution, why my Explorer Manager (either BeanTreeView or OutlineView) in NetBeans Platform 7.1 application works fine with tree structure, when deleting single Node, but not when **deleting multiple nodes**. The **problem is with the refreshing the tree, not with the deleting itself**.
When calling delete action (system action), it calls destroy() method on my Node:

```
@Override
public void destroy() throws IOException {
  //removing the business object
  ...

    try {
      IReloadableViewCapability rvc;
      if (getParentNode() != null) {
        rvc = this.getParentNode().getLookup().lookup(IReloadableViewCapability.class);
      }
      rvc.reloadChildren();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
    }

    fireNodeDestroyed();
}
```

And let's say, I have this structure:

- Node 1

  - 1.1
  - 1.2
  - 1.3
- Node 2

  - 2.1
  - ...

Now let's say, I want delete nodes 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3. I select them all, call the delete action and it calls **destroy() method of the node 1.1, where it deletes data for it and calls my reloadChildren() method on parentNode of the node 1.1** (as shown in the code above).
Then after deleting node 1.2, it comes to 1.3. **It deletes deletes data for 1.3, but now the getParentNode() returns null, even though, it again should return the Node 1**.

The similar problem occurs when deleting Node 1 and Node 2 together (or any other top nodes), even though, they are children of special RootNode node. The only difference in root is that there it goes ok only for the first node, but than any other one selected, can't find its parent.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Well the other thing is that it seems, the fireNodeDestroyed() does not lead to calling ndoeDestroyed overriden method in my node child factory, which implements NodeListener. That is why I call the reloadChildren and get the IReloadableViewCapability implementation, which is defined as anonymous class just in this same Node in constructor.

Comment: can you ensure the parent parent node is not destroyed in your call? Maybe that parent is a child of another node which is a child of the parent. Could you have possibly introduced a cycl(ic dependency)e into your tree?

Comment: Good point, but I really believe not. I tried to build the data, from the tree is generated several times. And my app yet allows only add another child, so there is no way to do a net hierarchy instead of tree. And if I call my reload action, which reloads the whole tree, all seems also ok.
Anyway, I edited the question, so now the example is better to understand.

Comment: After you have deleted the last child, to what object is the getParentNode() attached? What meaning could a call to getParentNode () have when all the children have been deleted?

Comment: Now I don't understand you, or you don't understand me. When deleting children 1.1 to 1.3 I get the null from getParentNode() on 1.3 (which I am deleting). And when deleting the nodes in first level (Node 1, 2...) I get it righ on the second one in row (so here, Node 2).

Comment: When deleting children 1.1 to 1.3 I get the null from getParentNode() called in the overriden destroy method of the node 1.3. In the "//removing the business object" part of the code, I only delete the object from the database. Then I try in the shown code to reload the children of the parent node (Node 1), so that the node 1.3 disappears from the tree. I don't delete the node manually anywhere, I just call DeleteAction.delete() from NB platform, which calls the overriden method destroy on the node being deleted. And when I delete all 3 nodes one by one,it works fine.Multiple selection is prob

Answer (score 0):

The better solution to this problem is just avoid calling parentNode, but change a bit my implementation of ChildFactory.
My CHildFactory now also implements NodeListener and in the nodeDestroyed overriden method it calls just:

```
refresh(true);
```

Then I have added the listener to the created node:

```
@Override
protected Node createNodeForKey(Chapters key) {
    ChapterNode chapterNode = new ChapterNode(key);

    chapterNode.addNodeListener(this);
    return chapterNode;
}
```

And then I have modified my node's destroy() method:

```
@Override
public void destroy() throws IOException {
    //removing the business object
    ...

    fireNodeDestroyed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your elements have not been attached to the dom tree yet. You have to attache them first, like: document.body.appendChild(myElement); Then you can remove them in IE like so: myElement.parentNode.removeChild(myElement);